# Button and button group with same width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Made [this](http://www.bootply.com/Lva1obFEBG) Bootply example and I'm wondering how can I get the same width for normal button and a button group consisting of 3 buttons.
Tried it with an css extension but I don't think that is the correct way in sense of the bootstrap grid system.

I know that there is something like .btn-group-justified but using of that class also changes the first ("<") and last element (">") width, but they should be fixed.

Any ideas?

```css
.menu_button {
    min-width: 170px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="btn-toolbar">
  <div class="btn-group">
   <button class="btn btn-default menu_button">First</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
   <button class="btn btn-default menu_button">Second</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
   <button class="btn btn-default">&lt;</button>
   <button class="btn btn-default menu_button">3rd</button>
   <button class="btn btn-default">&gt;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
   <button class="btn btn-default">&lt;</button>
   <button class="btn btn-default menu_button">4th</button>
   <button class="btn btn-default">&gt;</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to make each button the same size regardless if it's grouped or not?

Comment: @JasonBassett: btn-group 1/2 should have the same width as btn-group 3/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this?

I created a separate class for grouped buttons so that they could have separate stylings.

**SIDE NOTE**

Bootstrap buttons are styled to be responsive as the viewport changes. So styling them as you did may work, but may not be responsive unless you add your own media queries in CSS to change the size of them as the viewport changes.

```css
.menu_button {
    min-width: 170px !important;
    max-width: 200px !important;
}
.menu_button_grouped {
    min-width: 104px !important;
    max-width: 134px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="btn-toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group">
   <button class="btn btn-default menu_button">First</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
   <button class="btn btn-default menu_button">Second</button>
    </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
   <button class="btn btn-default">&lt;</button>
   <button class="btn btn-default menu_button_grouped">3rd</button>
   <button class="btn btn-default">&gt;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
   <button class="btn btn-default">&lt;</button>
   <button class="btn btn-default menu_button_grouped">4th</button>
   <button class="btn btn-default">&gt;</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. This one does the job! 
Although it is working now is a solution with the bootstrap grid with also possible?

Comment: Should be fine the way it is now. Unless the text that you will be adding to those buttons exceed a certain width then you will need to add media queries to make them more responsive. @Quartr

Answer (score 0):

```css
.buttons-group {
    min-width: -webkit-fill-available;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.button-group {
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value